# Comparison of groups with low N

Tags: dataset, small-sample

Recently, I have seen a study that was comparing three groups of subjects. Each of these groups had N=3 participants. The author was claiming very strong conclusions from the mean-differences of outcomes of treatment in between groups. Given this scarce dataset, can her claims in theory be backed up by any statistic test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible to get statistically significant results, but the conclusions may lack robustness to some of the assumptions.

For example, with a one-way ANOVA it's easily possible to get statistically significant differences with 3 groups of 3:

```
> dv=data.frame(vals=c(2,3,4,12,13,14,17,18,19),group=factor(rep(1:3,each=3)))
> dv
  vals group
1    2     1
2    3     1
3    4     1
4   12     2
5   13     2
6   14     2
7   17     3
8   18     3
9   19     3
> anova(lm(vals~group,dv))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: vals
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
group      2    350     175     175 4.787e-06 ***
Residuals  6      6       1                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Indeed, you can even get a significant result (at least with an $\alpha$ of 0.05) with a Kruskal Wallis test and 3 groups of 3.